# How to do unary and/reduction of bus to a bit in Perl?

Tags: perl, bit-manipulation

I have a variable `$A = 0x3`;

I want `$B` to be one i.e., AND-ing all the bits of variable `A`

Also how do I do the same with `OR`?

Have already tried `$B &= $A`, not working.

Comment: I am not sure I understand exactly.. What is your expected result for `$B` when `$A` is `0x3`?

Comment: expected result is 1 as 3 in binary is 11.

Comment: so you first convert `0x3` to binary `11`, then you do logical AND of all bits: `1 & 1` which gives the result 1? But if `0x3` is a byte then it is actually equal to `00000011` and you would get `0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1` which would give result 0. Do you chop off all leading zeros first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is "*not working*" (or what you are asking?)

How does this example

```
perl -wE'
    $v=0x3; $u = 0b010;
    printf "%6s = %#6b ($v)\n", "v", $v;
    printf "%6s = %#6b ($u)\n", "u", $u; 
    $r = $v & $u; 
    printf "%6s = %#6b ($r)\n", "v & u", $r'
```

relate to what you are doing?

It prints

```
     v =   0b11 (3)
     u =   0b10 (2)
 v & u =   0b10 (2)
```

Comment: I will try explaining in a more clear way. So i have $A = 0x03-> 8bit signal and i want all its bits to be and with each other and give the value in $B.

Comment: @AnupamDas OK ... but with 8 bits it's `00000011` so AND-ing all bits (for reduction) is `0&...`, as  Håkon explains in a comment under the question -- so it's always a `0`, if even just one bit is `0`.  Is that what you mean?  (Or AND all bits up to the highest non-zero bit?)  If you meant to AND each bit with 1 (so `0x03 & 0b11111111`) then it's just the number itself.  Can you explain?

Answer (score 2):

If `$A` is an 8-bit value, and if you want to AND all 8 bits with one another, you will always get `0` unless all 8 bits are `1`

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---------------------------------------+
| A7 | A6 | A5 | A4 | A3 | A2 | A1 | A0 | A7 & A6 & A5 & A4 & A3 & A2 & A1 & A0 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---------------------------------------+
|  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |                                     0 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---------------------------------------+
|  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |                                     0 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---------------------------------------+
|  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |                                     0 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---------------------------------------+
|  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  1 |                                     0 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---------------------------------------+
|  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  0 |                                     0 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---------------------------------------+
...
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---------------------------------------+
|  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  0 |                                     0 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---------------------------------------+
|  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |                                     1 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---------------------------------------+
```

This means you will get `0` unless `$A` is equal to `0b11111111` aka `0xFF` aka `255`. That means you can simply use the following:

```
my $B = $A == 255 ? 1 : 0;
```

---

The above solution is much simpler and quicker than using bitwise operations, but it is possible to use these.

To isolate a bit, one uses the following:

```
( $A >> $bitnum ) & 1
```

So the following would AND the 8 bits together:

```
my $B =
     ( ( $A >> 7 ) & 1 )
   & ( ( $A >> 6 ) & 1 )
   & ( ( $A >> 5 ) & 1 )
   & ( ( $A >> 4 ) & 1 )
   & ( ( $A >> 3 ) & 1 )
   & ( ( $A >> 2 ) & 1 )
   & ( ( $A >> 1 ) & 1 )
   & ( ( $A >> 0 ) & 1 );
```

Removing the redundant `& 1` give us the following simplified solution:

```
my $B = 1
   & ( $A >> 7 )
   & ( $A >> 6 )
   & ( $A >> 5 )
   & ( $A >> 4 )
   & ( $A >> 3 )
   & ( $A >> 2 )
   & ( $A >> 1 )
   & ( $A >> 0 );
```

In fact, because we're starting with an 8-bit value, the following is sufficient:

```
my $B =
     ( $A >> 7 )
   & ( $A >> 6 )
   & ( $A >> 5 )
   & ( $A >> 4 )
   & ( $A >> 3 )
   & ( $A >> 2 )
   & ( $A >> 1 )
   & ( $A >> 0 );
```

We can improve this by ANDing multiple bits at once!

```
 my $B = $A;
 $B &= $B >> 4;
 $B &= $B >> 2;
 $B &= $B >> 1;
```

Comment: And how do I do 'or' of all the bits of $A

Comment: Could you please tell me how to `or` all the bits of $A also please .Thanks in advance

Comment: In that situation, you will always get `1` unless all bits of `$A` are zero, so `$A == 0 ? 0 : 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$B = 0+!($A & ($A+1));
```

If `$A` = 2<sup>*n*</sup>-1 for some *n*, then `$A & ($A+1)` will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to AND together the bits up to the most-significant 1 bit,

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------------------------------------------+
| A7 | A6 | A5 | A4 | A3 | A2 | A1 | A0 |                                           |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------------------------------------------+
|  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |                                         0 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------------------------------------------+
|  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |                                    A0 = 1 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------------------------------------------+
|  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |                               A1 & A0 = 0 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------------------------------------------+
|  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  1 |                               A1 & A0 = 1 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------------------------------------------+
|  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  0 |                          A2 & A1 & A0 = 0 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------------------------------------------+
...
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------------------------------------------+
|  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  0 | A7 & A6 & A5 & A4 & A3 & A2 & A1 & A0 = 0 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------------------------------------------+
|  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 | A7 & A6 & A5 & A4 & A3 & A2 & A1 & A0 = 1 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-------------------------------------------+
```

I'd use a lookup table if you did this repeatedly.

```
my @B = (0) x 256;  $B[$_] = 1 for 0x01, 0x03, 0x07, 0x0F, 0x1F, 0x3F, 0x7F, 0xFF;

my $B = $B[$A];
```

You could also use [mob's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56131467/589924).

```
my $B = ( $A & ($A+1) ) ? 0 : 1;
```